# How to cast `[8 x i1]` to `i8` in LLVM IR

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing a compiler that generates LLVM IR. But the helper library ([ollvm](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ollvm)) I am using supports only three integer types: `i1`, `i32` and `i64`. However, I need byte (`i8`) values for chars and strings.

Currently I am trying to construct an `i8` value from eight `i1`s by casting `[8 x i1]` to `i8`.
The following code compiles but does not print the result that I expect.

```
define i32 @main() #0 {
  %arr = alloca [8 x i1], align 1
  store [8 x i1] [ i1 1, i1 0, i1 0, i1 0, i1 1, i1 0, i1 0, i1 0 ], [8 x i1]* %arr
  %ptr = getelementptr inbounds [8 x i1], [8 x i1]* %arr, i64 0, i64 0
  %ptr2 = bitcast i1* %ptr to i8*
  %result = load i8, i8* %ptr2, align 1
  call void @printByte(i8 noundef %result)
  ret i32 0
}
```

The `printByte` function is defined in C as follows.

```
void printByte(char x) {
    printf("%x", x);
}
```

This code prints `1` but I expect it to print `11` (hex value of `00010001`).

Moreover, all array values are ignored except for the first one. For instance, it prints `0` given `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` and prints `1` given `[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` (only the first value matters).

Can you please explain why this code works the way that it works and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The array type `[8 x i1]` has size 8 in LLVM.
So the line

```
store [8 x i1] [ i1 1, i1 0, i1 0, i1 0, i1 1, i1 0, i1 0, i1 0 ], [8 x i1]* %arr
```

sets 8 *bytes* to 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, not 8 *bits*.

Try

```
%arr = alloca [8 x i8]
store [8 x i8] [i8 1, i8 0, i8 0, i8 0, i8 1, i8 0, i8 0, i8 0], ptr %arr
%result = load i64, ptr %arr
ret i64 %result
```

This returns `0x100000001`.

Note that you should use the opaque `ptr` type instead of typed pointers and in general you don't need to `bitcast` between pointer types.

Comment: Thanks, chrysante! I thought that `[8 x i1]` occupied 1 byte... Could you please provide a reference to some document that states otherwise. Also, you provided the solution to the `[8 x i8]` to `i64` problem but is the original problem solvable?

Comment: I guess that depends on what your actual problem is. Why do you have the `[8 x i1]` array in the first place instead of an `i8`?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find anything in the lang-ref about the size of weird width integer arrays, but [here](https://godbolt.org/z/EcY5fcW3z) you see it clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the link. To answer your question, I cannot generate `i8` values since the library I use does not support it but I need them for strings. So I figured that I should be able to construct an `i8` value out of `i1`s. However, now I think that the better idea would be to cast `i32` to `i8` or `i64` to `i8` and so on